# Egit (local repository) and JavaEE : items don't seem in the index

Tags: eclipse, egit, git-commit

I am working alone with Eclipse (Kepler Service Release 2) and I am using Egit locally (the git repository is on my hard drive) mainly to benefit from versioning.

When I go to the ressources of the history view, I can only see this :

[image]

the name of my project with a green plus and the yellow cylinder. I can't compare anything and I suspect I am not commiting anything.
I can't add items of my project (I mean classes, jsp, and others) to the index, neither could I remove them from it, although every item's got the cylinder.
I made another git, attached my project to it. Nothing I do seems to matter.

I guess I am missing something basic but my local unusual usage makes finding information harder. How can I really add my items to the index and compare them through different versions ?

Comment: That looks like you accidentally have a repository within a repository (a Git submodule). What happens if you remove all the repositories from the *Git Repositories* view and on the project, click Team > Disconnect, and then Team > Share Project...?

Comment: I removed all gits from the view, disconnected the project, shared the project again, had to create a new git doing it. (Though no yellow cylinder on the name of the project in the explorer)
On the project, I clicked team > commit, but see :
http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/473953commitchangesproblem.jpg
there was only one file I could add with the name of the path with cylinder and plus. (And I guarantee there's more files in my project)